# How to convert a PL/PgSQL procedure into a dynamic one?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I am trying to write a plpgsql procedure to perform spatial tiling of a postGIS table. I can perform the operation successfully using the following procedure in which the table names are hardcoded. The procedure loops through the tiles in tile_table and for each tile clips the area_table and inserts it into split_table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE splitbytile()
AS $$
DECLARE
    tile RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tile IN 
        SELECT tid, geom FROM test_tiles ORDER BY tid 
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO split_table (id, areaname, ttid, geom)
        SELECT id, areaname, tile.tid,
        CASE WHEN st_within(base.geom, tile.geom) THEN st_multi(base.geom)
        ELSE st_multi(st_intersection(base.geom, tile.geom)) END as geom
        FROM area_table as base
        WHERE st_intersects(base.geom, tile.geom);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Having tested this successfully, now I need to convert it to a dynamic procedure where I can provide the table names as parameters. I tried the following partial conversion, using format() for inside of loop:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE splitbytile(in_table text, grid_table text, split_table text)
AS $$
DECLARE
    tile RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tile IN 
        EXECUTE format('SELECT tid, geom FROM %I ORDER BY tid', grid_table) 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 
            FORMAT(
                'INSERT INTO %1$I (id, areaname, ttid, geom)
                SELECT id, areaname, tile.tid,
                CASE WHEN st_within(base.geom, tile.geom) THEN st_multi(base.geom)
                ELSE st_multi(st_intersection(base.geom, tile.geom)) END as geom
                FROM %2$I as base
                WHERE st_intersects(base.geom, tile.geom)', split_table, in_table
            );
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

But it throws an error

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "tile"
```

So, how can I convert the procedure to a dynamic one? More specifically, how can I use the record data type (tile) returned by the for loop inside the loop? Note that it works when format is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE ... USING` to supply parameters to a dynamic query:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      'SELECT r FROM %I WHERE c = $1.val',
      table_name
   )
INTO result_var
USING record_var;
```

The first argument to `USING` will be used for `$1`, the second for `$2` and so on.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for details.

Comment: Your answer is really useful. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe. That pointed my in the right direction. However, I wasn't able to use `$1.val` and had to provide them separately in the `USING` expression.

Comment: Perhaps parentheses would help? `WHERE c = ($1).val`

Answer (score -1):

Personally I use somehow different way to create dynamic functions. By **concatination** and **execute** function. You can also do like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitbytile()
RETURNS void AS $$
declare 
result1 text;
table_name text := 'test_tiles';
msi text := '+7 9912 231';
msi text := 'Hello world';
code text := 'code_name';
_operator_id  integer := 2;
begin

        query1 := 'SELECT msisdn from ' || table_name || ' where msisdn = ''' || msi::text ||''';';
        query2 := 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || '(msisdn,usage,body,pr_code,status,sent_date,code_type,operator_id) 
         VALUES( ''' || msi::text || ''',' || true || ',''' || _body::text || ''',''' || code::text || ''',' || false || ',''' ||  time_now  || ''',' || kod_type || ',' || _operator_id  ||');';
        execute query1 into result1;
        execute query2;

END;
$function$
```

You just make your query as text then anywhere you want you can execute it. Maybe by checking result1 value inside If statement or smth like that.

Comment: I seem to be constructing the query as text correctly using format(). The issue is that when using string formatting the record variable becomes inaccessible.

Comment: This is a bad answer. The code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I agree with your idea. But it is also one way.

Comment: `format()` is a much better way to generate dynamic SQL